# Need help pivoting some data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm trying to pivot some data on SQL Server 2005 and can't quite get the results I'm looking for.

This is my current table schema:

```
| ProductCode | AttributeName | AttributeValue |
| 1           | AttributeA    | 10             |
| 1           | AttributeB    | 20             |
| 2           | AttributeA    | 30             |
| 2           | AttributeB    | 40             |
| 3           | AttributeA    | 50             |
```

This is the results I'm trying to achieve:

```
| ProductCode | AttributeA | AttributeB |
| 1           | 10         | 20         |
| 2           | 30         | 40         |
| 3           | 50         | NULL       |
```

I know that I can achieve this result with the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductCode, 
    (SELECT AttributeValue 
     FROM attributes 
     WHERE ProductName = 'AttributeA' AND ProductCode=a.ProductCode) AttributeA, 
    (SELECT AttributeValue 
     FROM attributes 
     WHERE ProductName = 'AttributeB' AND ProductCode=a.ProductCode) AttributeB, 
FROM attributes a
```

Although that SQL does produce the result I'm looking for, it's obviously not dynamic (in reality, I not only have more Attribute Types, but different products have different sets of attributes) and it also scans the table 3 times. It's also a maintenance nightmare.

I tried using the PIVOT functionality of SQL Server, but with no luck.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #attributes (ProductCode int, 
                          AttributeName varchar(20), 
                          AttributeValue int)

insert into #attributes values (1, 'AttributeA', 10)
insert into #attributes values (1, 'AttributeB', 20)
insert into #attributes values (2, 'AttributeA', 30)
insert into #attributes values (2, 'AttributeB', 40)
insert into #attributes values (3, 'AttributeA', 50)

declare @attributes_columns nvarchar(max)

set @attributes_columns
   = (
    select ', [' + AttributeName + ']'
    from 
    (
        select distinct AttributeName as AttributeName
        from #attributes
    ) t
    order by t.AttributeName
    for xml path('')
   )
set @attributes_columns = stuff(@attributes_columns,1,2,'')

declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql = N'
select ProductCode, <attributes_columns>
from
 (select ProductCode, AttributeName, AttributeValue
  from #attributes )p
 pivot 
 (
   sum(AttributeValue) for AttributeName in (<attributes_columns>)
 ) as pvt
'
set @sql = replace(@sql, '<attributes_columns>', @attributes_columns)
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
drop table #attributes
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I plugged this in, and it worked great - except for two runtime errors: (1) the inserts and (2) initializing a local variable when declared. I'm using SQL2005, so I'm guessing that's the reason. Do you know of any way of using this logic inside of a table function? I played around with it and because it's so dynamic, I don't think it works with table functions (and thus must be a SP). The downside to a SP is that I can't join to it. And again, thanks!

Comment: Welcome, sorry for didn't testing it on SQL2005, I amended it

Comment: You can't use it in a table function, since "In inline table-valued functions, the TABLE return value is defined through a single SELECT statement." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Comment: However, you said that the Attributes are not so volatile, so you can use the generated statement in a table function